# IntelliJ VCS Background Task Hanging

Tags: intellij-idea

I am commiting changes to my repo but the VCS window is just hanging and not doing anything.

[image]

I found this link:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79476

No solutions yet?

Comment: I would love to see a solution which does not involve restarting Intellij

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Invalidate the caches and restart IDEA.

Comment: This is great and does the job, but I would be particularly interested to see a solution which does not involve restarting Intellij.

Comment: @MMans I have not had this problem for quite some time.  Currently using IntelliJ 15.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me (PHPStorm >= 9) :-(

Comment: @user1983686 does it hang the first time it runs after a full system restart?  Btw this was for intellij not phpstorm... but they do share a code base.

Comment: @BAR it hangs on every commit. I noticed today the background task actually finishes but it takes ages. I have this issue for about  2 Weeks and have no idea what's causing it.

Comment: @user1983686 Try upgrading to the most recent version of phpstorm.  If that does not work, file an issue on their jira.

Comment: @BAR I upgraded to v10 today but it did not help. Filing a bug makes sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BAR Yes, Since upgrading to v15 I have not experience this problem with VCS Background Task Hanging

Comment: I have the same problem, Invalidate and restart do not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that rebuilding the project (Build --> Rebuild project) did the trick.  At the end of that task it says... saving cashes.  Immediately thereafter I can commit with no delay.